# half image displayed when converted blob type to base64 in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {
        $image = $row['image'];

        if($counter == 0)
        {
            $Indicators .='<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="'.$counter.'" class="active"></li>';
            $slides .= '<div class="item active">
            <div class="fill">
            <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($image).'" alt="photo"></div>
          </div>';

        }
        else
        {
            $Indicators .='<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="'.$counter.'"></li>';
            $slides .= '<div class="item"><div class="fill">
            <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($image).'" alt="photo"></div>

          </div>';
        }
        $counter++;
    }
```

Little portion from top to somewhere in middle of image is displayed.I have stored images in mysql database and type of image is blob.When trying to convert and display using php they appear to be half cut from bottom ot i think they are not converted fully.
Original image:[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi9d0.jpg)
After converting in base64 image displays as below:[Converted image to base64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSLb5.png)

Comment: I had same issue long back, it was issue with blob size. change field type to `longblob` and then save image into database. Hope this will resolve the issue

Comment: ok sir will try it and reply back if it works thanks in advanced

Comment: thanx sir it worked....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use just `BLOB` it is not enough to store image data which you provided in question, you have to use instead `MEDIUMBLOB` or `LONGBLOB`

max size of

```
BLOB: ~ 63KB
MEDIUMBLOB: ~ 16MB
LONGBLOB: ~ 4GB
```

More information about the length of `BLOB` and other `MySql` fields you can see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: Sir i have same issue in asp.net i changed blob to longblob but no change.It worked in php but not working in asp.net c#

Comment: <img runat="server" id="prodImgThumb" src='<%# "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])(Eval("image_byteImage"))) %>' /></a>